# Garamondx does not work anymore in MiKTeX

Tags: fonts, miktex, garamondx

During an update of MiKTeX in December 2016, the garamondx package has been marked as obsolete and removed automatically. I re-installed the package in a local tree according to the documentation in the README file. pdflatex, invoked from a command line, however, keeps failing. Using the minimal example

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, DIV=9]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{garamondx}

\begin{document}
Hello world.
\end{document}
```

the following error message occurs:

```
Trying to make PK font zgmr8r at 657 DPI...
Sorry, but makepk did not succeed.
The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
  C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makepk.log
You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file zgmr8r): Font zgmr8r at 657 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

This is the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.7.30)  27 JAN 2017 20:52
entering extended mode
**./Test.tex
(Test.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 2
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrartcl.cls"
Document Class: scrartcl 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script document class (article)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrkbase.sty"
Package: scrkbase 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent b
asics and keyval usage)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrbase.sty"
Package: scrbase 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrlfile.sty"
Package: scrlfile 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (loading files)

Package scrlfile, 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

))) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\tocbasic.sty"
Package: tocbasic 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
\scr@dte@tocline@numberwidth=\skip41
\scr@dte@tocline@numbox=\box26
)
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `toc'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `toc' on input line 130.
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lof'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lof' on input line 131.
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lot'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lot' on input line 132.
Class scrartcl Info: File `scrsize11pt.clo' used to setup font sizes on input l
ine 2052.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrsize11pt.clo"
File: scrsize11pt.clo 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt
)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\typearea.sty"
Package: typearea 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (type area)

Package typearea, 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (type area)
                  Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-

\ta@bcor=\skip42
\ta@div=\count79
\ta@hblk=\skip43
\ta@vblk=\skip44
\ta@temp=\skip45
\footheight=\skip46
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 9
(typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 398.33862pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -1%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 27.31467pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = 27.31467pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 568.60025pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -15.7759pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 17.0pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 20.40001pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 11.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 47.6pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 13.6pt
(typearea)              on input line 1529.
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\scr@dte@part@maxnumwidth=\skip47
\scr@dte@section@maxnumwidth=\skip48
\scr@dte@subsection@maxnumwidth=\skip49
\scr@dte@subsubsection@maxnumwidth=\skip50
\scr@dte@paragraph@maxnumwidth=\skip51
\scr@dte@subparagraph@maxnumwidth=\skip52
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textsubscript on input line 4036.
\abovecaptionskip=\skip53
\belowcaptionskip=\skip54
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box27
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
Class scrartcl Info: Redefining `\numberline' on input line 5049.
\bibindent=\dimen102
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks15
\inpenc@posthook=\toks16

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\utf8.def"
File: utf8.def 2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
Now handling font encoding OML ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML
Now handling font encoding T1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T1

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.dfu"
File: t1enc.dfu 2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
)
Now handling font encoding OT1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OT1

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ot1enc.dfu"
File: ot1enc.dfu 2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
)
Now handling font encoding OMS ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMS

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omsenc.dfu"
File: omsenc.dfu 2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
)
Now handling font encoding OMX ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMX
Now handling font encoding U ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding U
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2017/01/24 v2.0c Standard LaTeX package

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"
File: t1enc.def 2017/01/24 v2.0c Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty"
Package: babel 2016/04/23 3.9r The Babel package

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\babel-german\ngerman.ldf"
Language: ngerman 2016/11/02 v2.9 German support for babel (new orthography)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\babel-german\ngermanb.ldf"
Language: ngermanb 2016/11/02 v2.9 German support for babel (new orthography)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def"
File: babel.def 2016/04/23 3.9r Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count88
\U@D=\dimen103
)
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 125.
)))
(C:\Users\Matthias\Dropbox\LaTeX-Private\tex\latex\garamondx\garamondx.sty
Package: garamondx 2016/12/24 v1.1

`garamondx' v1.1. 2016/12/24 GaramondNo8 with expert features (Michael Sharpe)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2016/10/09 v1.0u Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2017/01/12 v0.06k Graphics/color for pdfTeX

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count89
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen104
\Gin@req@width=\dimen105
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2017/01/24 v2.0c Standard LaTeX package

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ly1\ly1enc.def"
File: ly1enc.def 2009/07/22 v0.7 TeX 'n ANSI encoding (DPC/KB)
Now handling font encoding LY1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding LY1

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ly1enc.dfu"
File: ly1enc.dfu 2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"
File: t1enc.def 2017/01/24 v2.0c Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+ptm on input line 105.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\t1ptm.fd"
File: t1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for T1/ptm.
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontaxes\fontaxes.sty"
Package: fontaxes 2014/03/23 v1.0d Font selection axes
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 29.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 31.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 33.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 37.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\textcomp.sty"
Package: textcomp 2017/01/24 v2.0c Standard LaTeX package
Package textcomp Info: Sub-encoding information:
(textcomp)               5 = only ISO-Adobe without \textcurrency
(textcomp)               4 = 5 + \texteuro
(textcomp)               3 = 4 + \textohm
(textcomp)               2 = 3 + \textestimated + \textcurrency
(textcomp)               1 = TS1 - \textcircled - \t
(textcomp)               0 = TS1 (full)
(textcomp)             Font families with sub-encoding setting implement
(textcomp)             only a restricted character set as indicated.
(textcomp)             Family '?' is the default used for unknown fonts.
(textcomp)             See the documentation for details.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ? sub-encoding to TS1/1 on input line 79.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1enc.def"
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
Now handling font encoding TS1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding TS1

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1enc.dfu"
File: ts1enc.dfu 2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
))
LaTeX Info: Redefining \oldstylenums on input line 334.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 349.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 350.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 351.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 352.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmbr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 353.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 354.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ccr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 355.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptm sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 356.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pcr sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 357.
Package textcomp Info: Setting phv sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 358.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ppl sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 359.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pag sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 360.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pbk sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 361.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pnc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 362.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pzc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 363.
Package textcomp Info: Setting bch sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 364.
Package textcomp Info: Setting put sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 365.
Package textcomp Info: Setting uag sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 366.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ugq sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 367.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ul8 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 368.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ul9 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 369.
Package textcomp Info: Setting augie sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 370.
Package textcomp Info: Setting dayrom sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 371.
Package textcomp Info: Setting dayroms sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 372.

Package textcomp Info: Setting pxr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 373.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 374.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 375.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 376.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 377.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 378.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 379.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmdh sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 380.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 381.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmssq sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 382.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 383.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 384.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qhv sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 385.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qag sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 386.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qbk sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 387.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qcr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 388.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qcs sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 389.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qpl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 390.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qtm sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 391.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qzc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 392.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qhvc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 393.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futs sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 394.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 395.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 396.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlh sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 397.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hls sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 398.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlst sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 399.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlct sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 400.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlx sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 401.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlce sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 402.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcn sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 403.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcw sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 404.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcf sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 405.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pplx sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 406.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pplj sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 407.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 408.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 409.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty"
Package: etoolbox 2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count90
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+zgmx on input line 182.


(C:\Users\Matthias\Dropbox\LaTeX-Private\tex\latex\garamondx\t1zgmx.fd
File: t1zgmx.fd 2012/10/29 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for T1/zgmx.
))
(Test.aux)
\openout1 = `Test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for LY1/ptm/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for LY1+ptm on input line 11.
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ly1\ly1ptm.fd"
File: ly1ptm.fd 2001/02/01 font definitions for LY1/ptm using Berry names.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for TS1+cmr on input line 11.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1cmr.fd"
File: ts1cmr.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\grfext.sty"
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvdefinekeys.sty"
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
38.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 456.
)
\c@mv@tabular=\count91
\c@mv@boldtabular=\count92
 [1

{C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (Test.aux) 
) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 5409 strings out of 493334
 85061 string characters out of 3139300
 228106 words of memory out of 3000000
 8864 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 17070 words of font info for 21 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 49i,6n,51p,8817b,148s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file zgmr8r): Font zgmr8r at 657 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The makepk log file does not contain any useful hint:

```
2017-01-27 20:53:00,463+0100 INFO  makepk - Trying to make PK font zgmr8r at 657 DPI...
```

I am afraid I have missed some step during the manual re-installation of the garamondx package. What can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: Mentioning ‘Trying to make PK font’ is already a useful hint…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to write this line in the   `updmap.cfg`  file in `Local root\miktex\config` (if the file doesn't exist, create it):

```
Map zgm.map
```

Then run from the command line (as administrator): `updmap.exe --verbose` (the switch is to read what happens).
 This will regenerate `dvips.map` & friends, which are databases of available postscript fonts on the system. Then, the compiler will no more try to make bitmap font files.

Comment: How in hell do you know that? :)

Comment: I've been fiddling with postscript fonts in LaTeX for more than 20 years, and I had time to learn! ;o)

Comment: More seriously, it's the general procedure to make an effective use of ps fonts in TeX, without bitmaps.

Comment: @Bernard Incredible! This fully solves my problem. Thanks a lot for your quick reply.

Comment: B.t.w., it happens from time to time with MiKTeX, that you install a font package, and when you use this font in document, it tries to make .pk fonts. This  means dvips, or pdflatex, doesn't find the type 1 version of the fonts because dvips.map, or pdftex.map,  was not updated. The solution simply consists in running `updmap.exe` as administrator from the command line.

Comment: Good to know! - You seem to be _the_ LaTeX type 1 expert.

Comment: I wouldn't say so, really. I'm a man who experienced some problems with fonts under MiKTeX.