# Garamond- Mathdesign

Tags: fonts, garamond

Referring to [Garamondx does not work anymore in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350790/garamondx-does-not-work-anymore-in-miktex) ...

I'm a beginner in latex, and I'd like to include this package, because I used it last year and now I can't TT.TT, but I don't understand what are they saying, could someone give me clear instructions? for dummies, please. I'm a windows' 10 user. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Install Garamondx font properly? Don't know how to create bitmap font for zgmr8r](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110057/how-to-install-garamondx-font-properly-dont-know-how-to-create-bitmap-font-for)

Comment: @HenriMenke Is that for MiKTeX too?

Comment: No it isn't.  Close vote retracted.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you install `garamondx` in a local TeXMF tree?

Comment: @Bernard I don't know why garamondx is obsolete now :C On the other hand, I'm a beginner in latex, I use overleaf and there \usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign} worked while garamondx don't, but I wanted to install MiKTeX and Texmaker in my computer, because there's an image restriction in overleaf. Nevertheless, the \usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign} don't work, and appear errors like "citation ... undefined"... The point is, I don't know about installing packages in MiKTeX, even more, fonts packages.

Comment: That's not an error. Just a warning. It means you need to run BibTeX or Biber and then recompile twice more. OverLeaf does this automatically, but your editor may not. (Depends on configuration.)

Comment: `garamondx` is not obsolete as a package i.e. not marked as such on CTAN. I don't know how MikTeX decides what to include. (`garamondx` is not in, and never has been in, TeX Live, so there you need `getnonfreefonts-sys`.)

Comment: When I use \usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign} .Texmaker: !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ugmm8a.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!... 
With \usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign} PDF appear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `Garamondx`, it is rather easy, as there exists  a ready-to-install .zip file. Here are the details:

- Go to [this page](https://ctan.org/pkg/garamondx) on CTAN and download `garamondx.tds.zip`.
- If you have a Local TeXMF directory, unzip the  contents of this file in this directory.
- If you don't, create one, say `C:\LocalTeXMF`, and validate it as TeX root directory via `MiKTeX Settings (Admin)`, `Roots` tab, like this (it's my personal configuration, which uses another partition):

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJHfT.png)

- Refresh the `FNDB` with `MiKTeX Settings (Admin)`, `General` tab.
- You need a `updmap.cfg` file, which is  a plain text file, in which you write these lines:
  `#Garamondx
  Map zgm.map`

This file is used to add the Garamondx font files to the database of type1 fonts.

If it does not exist, create it and place it in `LocalTeXMF\miktex\config`.

- Last step: to update the databases (`psfonts.map` and its siblings), run from the command line, as administrator: `updmap --verbose` (the ‘verbose’ switch is used to display what happens).

That's all: from now on, the font can be used in TeX documents.

**Urw-Garamond**

For `urw-garamond`, it is a little more complex, because there is no ready-to-install .zip file. You can download`garamond.zip` from [this page](https://ctan.org/pkg/urw-garamond),unzip it in some directory , and copy the different files in the relevant subdirectories in `LocalTeXMF`, according to the T.D.S. (‘TeX Directory Structure’) and refresh the FNDB.

Finally, add to `updmap.cfg` the lines

`#urw-garamond
Map ugm.map`

and run `updmap` from the command line.

Comment: I have never seen a font installation so clearly explained.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Bernard, I had to install both and now it works! Easy to understand <3 :3

Comment: @Bernard I found this especially helpful, thank you writing this out so clearly!

Answer (score 1):

You can install getnonfreefonts first (refer to http://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/) and run `getnonfreefonts --sys garamond` from a command line. Then, include `\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}` in the head of your tex file. I've tried it and it works!