# How to use garamondx

Tags: garamondx

I like very much garamondx package and I spend several hours trying to figure out how to run it (so far unsuccessful).  I am using Miktex 2.9 and whenever I run my LaTeX file with the garamondx package I get the following comment:

"
Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed for the following reason:

PK font zgmr8r could not be created.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

C:/Users/M/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makepk.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
 )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file zgmr8r): Font zgmr8r at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
"

Can somebody help me ? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This message shows MiKTeX tries to make bitmap fonts for Garamondx, which means it doesn't find the type 1 fonts. Please see the description of the procedure in my answer to [this similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371145/garamond-mathdesign/371216#371216).

Comment: Dear Bernard: Many thanks for your comment. I would like to ask you a trivial question. My Miktex2.9 is in this folder: (C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9). When you say "Local TeXMF directory" do you mean this folder?

Comment: No, not in the distribution directory (there might be probllems on updating). For personal additions, you have to define a new  root directory and validate it with MiKTeX Settings (`Roots` tab). This directory must be organised according to the TDS, but with garamondx that's no problem since there's a ready-to-install version

Comment: Dear Bernard: I am really sorry for asking stupid questions. My Miktex is Miktex2.9 and I can only find MikTeX console, which doesn't have "General tab" to refresh "FNDB".

Comment: Oh! yes. It all has changed with the last updates. Everything is to be found in MiKTeX console now (hope there's no bug, as it's new!). Select `Settings` on the left hand side, then the `Directories` tab. You see, above a window that displays the different roots known to MiKTeX, a `+` button, which is done to add new directories.

Comment: Great. So I have added the text "#Garamondx Map zgm.map" into updmap.cfg file and placed it in the folder "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\config"

Comment: Now I run garamondx-doc from garamondx package and I get this comment : Couldn't open `T1-zgm-r-lf-s.cfg'  


Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed for the following reason:

  No creation rule for font T1-zgm-r-lf-swq.

Comment: updmap.cfg should be in TeXMFLocal, not in the distribution updmap.cfg (it can be overwritten on future updates), and you (normally) should refresh the FNDB  (see the `tasks` menu) and, last run `updmap.exe --verbose` (as administrator and as user) from the command line to refresh the type1 fonts database, as explained in the link I gave.

Comment: OK. I want to give up. I don't understand why is not working. I spent 5 hours on it now. Anyway. Thank you very much Bernard

Comment: It's not working very probably because you didn't refresh the FNDB and the font map files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74219/discussion-between-mo-b-and-bernard).